# using npm exiftool (javascript) async problem

Tags: javascript, npm, exiftool

I'm having trouble using npm exiftool. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/exiftool) I'm trying to do some stuffs using that.

1. Iterate images files through specific folder
2. Get 'xpKeywords' data of each image files.
3. Write file storing data.

Here's my code.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const exif = require('exiftool');
const folderName = 'testImages';
const inputPath = `/Users/myName/Project/project/${folderName}`;
const files = fs.readdirSync(inputPath, 'utf8');

let data = [];

(async () => {
  let promises = [];
  files.forEach(file => promises.push(fs.readFileSync(`${inputPath}/${file}`)));
  let results = await Promise.all(promises);
  for(let [index, result] of results.entries()) {
    let datum = await getMetadata(result, index);
    console.log("out");
    data.push(datum);
  }
  fs.writeFileSync('outputData/metaData.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 4), (error) => {
    console.log('Error Occurred');
  });
})();

async function getMetadata(result, index) {
  console.log(`get metadata ${index}`);
  await exif.metadata(result, (err, metadata) => {
    return {
      name: files[index],
      hashTags: metadata.xpKeywords
    };
  });
}
```

After running that code, the file metaData.json is not what I'd expected.

[
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
]

I think I'm having some trouble about the usage of async function in function getMetadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems there.

- The chief one is that `getMetaData` doesn't return anything. Returning from the *callback* that you give `exif.metadata` doesn't do anything to set the return value of `getMetaData`.
- Separately, [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) doesn't return a promise, so there's no point to the `let results = await Promise.all(promises);` call. (As the name suggests, it does its work **synchronously**.)
- Referencing files via indexes into a module global is error-prone.

To use promises, you can use Node.js's currently-experimental [promises file API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api), or use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) on `fs.readFile` (that's the version that's actually asynchronous, using a callback). You can also use `promisify` on `exif.metadata` if you want to get a promise-enabled version of that.

[This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) go into more detail about converting a callback-based API to promises.

Keeping all that in mind, I think you're looking for something along these lines (may need tweaking):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {promisify} = require('util');
const exif = require('exiftool');

const pReaddir = promisify(fs.readdir);
const pReadFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
const pWriteFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);
const pMetadata = promisify(exif.metadata);

const folderName = 'testImages';
const inputPath = `/Users/myName/Project/project/${folderName}`;

(async () => {
    // Get the file names
    const files = await pReaddir(inputPath, 'utf8');
    // Process the files in parallel and wait for the result
    const data = Promise.all(files.map(async(name) => {
        // Read this file and get its metadata from it
        let {xpKeywords: hashTags} = await pMetadata(await pReadFile(`${inputPath}/${name}`));
        // Return an object with the file's name and xpKeywords as its hashTags
        return {name, hashTags};
    }));
    // Write the results to file
    await pWriteFile('outputData/metaData.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
})()
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```